# Install custom rom ACE PLUS without voiding warranty

Tags: custom-roms, samsung-galaxy-ace-plus

I read somewhere that we can install custom ROM in our devices without voiding warranty ace plus is not getting updates soon.

Is there any method by which  we can install that and please suggest a good custom rom.

thanks

Comment: If you live outside the EU, I very much doubt you can install a Custom ROM without voiding your warranty. For the other part of the question, please see [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/16575)

Comment: but i read somewhere we can install and something about counter and all i dont remember was written

Comment: and i went through this question but can't get a good custom from from these sites

Comment: The counter is one thing for tracking. But in case you "brick" your device, and have to turn it in to the service center without being able to restore to stock, an "untouched" counter doesn't help: service can clearly see the custom ROM. If they care, that is.

Comment: ok thanks @Izzy and can you please suggest a good custom rom coz i can't find a good 1

Comment: Sorry, I don't know one from my own experience (don't have this device). But you cannot have checked the list thoroughly: What about [CyanogenMod for Ace Plus](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=36420972)? Just try [this Google Search](http://www.google.de/search?q=%22galaxy+ace+plus%22+cyanogenmod&ie=UTF-8) for more hits ;)

Comment: thanks buddy but i tried and havent found anything good but thnx for your response..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>Sum-up from the comments:</sup>

### Warranty

First, at least as of today and outside the EU, it is not possible to install a custom ROM or even only root your phone without voiding your warranty. Even if it can be done in a way not increasing a (possibly existing) "flash-counter": In case your device "bricks" for some reason, not giving you a chance to restore to "stock", your custumizations would be found in the service center.

### Existing Custom-ROMs

As said, here you might want to take a look into the question [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/16575), which lists a lot of ressources where to find different Custom ROMs. A good choice might be CyanogenMod, which is e.g. dealt with in the XDA-Developers thread about [CyanogenMod for Ace Plus](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=36420972). To find more details, you can simply use [this Google Search](http://www.google.de/search?q=%22galaxy+ace+plus%22+cyanogenmod&ie=UTF-8).